# I have a something in my vimrc to match text over 80 characters as an error. It only works in the right most split. Any ideas?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, split

From my .vimrc: `match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'`

And a screenshot: [image]

I have tried a minimal vimrc and it still doesn't work in the left splits.

Comment: What colour scheme is that? It looks quite nice.

Comment: https://github.com/scwood/vim-hybrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help :match`:

> Define a pattern to highlight in the **current** window

This is fixed by making the original command into an autocommand:

`autocmd WinEnter * match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'`

Answer (score 5):

Recent Vim versions have the `'colorcolumn'` option. It provides the following
benefits:

- You can just globally `:set` it; no `:autocmd` is needed.
- You get to keep the `:match` highlighting for something else.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of this setting, I'm just not a fan of having a huge line in my buffers.